# Handling a blobstore blob as a file (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I want to create a process using GAE by which, given a url, a file is downloaded and stored as a blob in the blobstore. Once this is done I want to pass this blob along as POST data to a second url. However for this second part to work I need to be able to open the blob as a file instance.

I've figured out how to do the first part

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from google.appengine.api import files

imagefile = urllib2.urlopen('fileurl')
# Create the file
file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type=imagefile.headers['Content-Type'])
# Open the file and write to it
with files.open(file_name, 'ab') as f:
    f.write(imagefile.read())
# Finalize the file. Do this before attempting to read it.
files.finalize(file_name)
# Get the file's blob key
blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(file_name)
```

But I can't figure out how to do the second part. So far I've tried

1. `ffile = files.open(files.blobstore.get_file_name(blob_key), 'r')`
2. `from google.appengine.ext import blobstore`

   ```
   ffile = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key)
   ```
3. `from google.appengine.ext import blobstore`

   ```
   ffile = blobstore.BlobInfo.open(blobstore.BlobInfo(blob_key))
   ```

All of which gives `False`for `isinstance(ffile, file)`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since my error seems to occur further downstream I've posted an expanded question at [Downloading file to GAE then uploading it to MediaWiki using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246491/downloading-file-to-gae-then-uploading-it-to-mediawiki-using-python). Figured that since this involved the added complexity of the MW-api it was better treated as a new post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ffile = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key)` works. However, the returned object has only a *file-like* interface; it dosn't extend a file-class. Therefore, the isinstance test wont work. Try something like `if ffile and "read" in dir( ffile )`.

Comment: Thanks. This probably means the error preventing me from passing the file along is occurring further downstream.

Answer (score 1):

To read file_data from the blobstore :

```
blob_key = .....                                        # is what you have
file_name = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key).filename   # the name of the file (image) to send 
blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key)
file_data = blob_reader.read()                          # and the file data with the image
```

But you can also send an url with the blob_key and serve the url. And for images you do not have to serve the images yourself, because you can post a get_serving_url, making use of the Google High Perfomance Image Serving API with dynamic scaling. Serving images this way is also very cheap.

Here is an example of such an url :

https://lh6.ggpht.com/lOghqU2JrYk8M-Aoio8WjMM6mstgZcTP0VzJk79HteVLhnwZy0kqbgVGQZYP8YsoqVNzsu0EBysX16qMJe7H2BsOAr4j=s70

Comment: Thanks. Since I need to pass the file on as http POST I don't think I can use the serving_url though.

Comment: I can read the image data now using the blob_reader.read(). I still can't get the overall program to work either by passing the blob_reader or the file_data to the second webpage so I think the error is further downstream.